# C#:How to get Daum TV player video file real Url?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Note**: To use Orbit Downloader Grab++ can get the file real download Url,but I want to get it using C#.

For example:http://tvpot.daum.net/v/v0fdatJtMw8tJMB8tmrJeAA

I have seen some code about **youtube** download for using c#,but it seems that it is not fit for daum tv.I observed the js code about the video page.
it looks like below:

```
<embed src="/controller/player/VodPlayer.swf" name="v0fdatJtMw8tJMB8tmrJeAA" width="100%" height="100%" allowscriptaccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" bgcolor="#000000" wmode="transparent" flashvars="jsCallback=true&amp;playLoc=tvpot&amp;profileName=MAIN&amp;autoPlay=true&amp;forceWide=false&amp;jsCallback=true&amp;permitWideScreen=true&amp;startNotReport=&amp;vid=v0fdatJtMw8tJMB8tmrJeAA&amp;currentVid=v0fdatJtMw8tJMB8tmrJeAA&amp;HTMLVodPlayerContainerId=videoViewer&amp;isTest=&amp;permitWideScreen=true">
```

May I use the embed source to get the real url of this video?
I Just know the video id in daum tv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i am not sure why your question is tagged with asp.net

But to get the download link of your video you can do a simple get request with the video id

Url : `http://videofarm.daum.net/controller/api/closed/v1_2/IntegratedMovieData.json?vid={VIDEO_ID}`

Video Id = `v0fdatJtMw8tJMB8tmrJeAA` (in your case).

This url will give u a JSON format response,which will contain the download link to it at `location.url`.

Sample response :

```
{
    "svcname":"insoya",
    "logo":{
        "status":"NO_LOGO"
    },
    "is_tvpot_post":"true",
    "is_youth_pest_video":"false",
    "location":{
        "type":"DATA",
        "url":"http://cdn.videofarm.daum.net/vod/v0fdatJtMw8tJMB8tmrJeAA/mp4_360P_1M_T1/movie.mp4?px-time=1443378652&px-hash=744c6a6d6728015be461f5ee3ba39d90&px-bps=1439735&px-bufahead=10",
        "profile":"MAIN"
    },
    "chapters":{
        "count":"6",
        "chapters":[
            {
                "timeInSec":"0",
                "num":"0",
                "thumbnail":"http://t1.daumcdn.net/thumb/C138x78/?fname=http%3A%2F%2Ft1.daumcdn.net%2Ftvpot%2Fthumb%2Fv0fdatJtMw8tJMB8tmrJeAA%2F0.png"
            },
            {
                "timeInSec":"22",
                "num":"1",
                "thumbnail":"http://t1.daumcdn.net/thumb/C138x78/?fname=http%3A%2F%2Ft1.daumcdn.net%2Ftvpot%2Fthumb%2Fv0fdatJtMw8tJMB8tmrJeAA%2F1.png"
            },
            {
                "timeInSec":"44",
                "num":"2",
                "thumbnail":"http://t1.daumcdn.net/thumb/C138x78/?fname=http%3A%2F%2Ft1.daumcdn.net%2Ftvpot%2Fthumb%2Fv0fdatJtMw8tJMB8tmrJeAA%2F2.png"
            },
            {
                "timeInSec":"66",
                "num":"3",
                "thumbnail":"http://t1.daumcdn.net/thumb/C138x78/?fname=http%3A%2F%2Ft1.daumcdn.net%2Ftvpot%2Fthumb%2Fv0fdatJtMw8tJMB8tmrJeAA%2F3.png"
            },
            {
                "timeInSec":"89",
                "num":"4",
                "thumbnail":"http://t1.daumcdn.net/thumb/C138x78/?fname=http%3A%2F%2Ft1.daumcdn.net%2Ftvpot%2Fthumb%2Fv0fdatJtMw8tJMB8tmrJeAA%2F4.png"
            },
            {
                "timeInSec":"111",
                "num":"5",
                "thumbnail":"http://t1.daumcdn.net/thumb/C138x78/?fname=http%3A%2F%2Ft1.daumcdn.net%2Ftvpot%2Fthumb%2Fv0fdatJtMw8tJMB8tmrJeAA%2F5.png"
            }
        ]
    },
    "status":"AVAILABLE",
    "output_list":{
        "standard_profile":"MAIN",
        "count":"4",
        "standard_preset":"mp4_360P_1M_T1",
        "output_list":[
            {
                "filesize":"4221475",
                "duration":"134",
                "height":"240",
                "width":"426",
                "state":"DONE",
                "label":"240P",
                "preset":"mp4_240P_200K_T1",
                "profile":"LOW"
            },
            {
                "filesize":"19292453",
                "duration":"134",
                "height":"360",
                "width":"640",
                "state":"DONE",
                "label":"360P+",
                "preset":"mp4_360P_1M_T1",
                "profile":"MAIN"
            },
            {
                "filesize":"10925203",
                "duration":"134",
                "height":"360",
                "width":"640",
                "state":"DONE",
                "label":"360P",
                "preset":"mp4_360P_500K_T1",
                "profile":"BASE"
            },
            {
                "filesize":"36732582",
                "duration":"134",
                "height":"720",
                "width":"1280",
                "state":"DONE",
                "label":"720P HD",
                "preset":"mp4_720P_2M_T1",
                "profile":"HIGH"
            }
        ]
    },
    "ownerid":"S6sTb99wgWw0",
    "is_geo_block":"false",
    "xylophone_req":{
        "postroll":{
            "imp_request":{
                "dsp_data":{
                    "slotid":"05N54",
                    "test":"N",
                    "ver":"1.0",
                    "ownerid":"S6sTb99wgWw0",
                    "vid":"v0fdatJtMw8tJMB8tmrJeAA"
                },
                "cp_id":"81PaW",
                "replay":"#IMP_REQUEST__REPLAY#",
                "content_id":"v0fdatJtMw8tJMB8tmrJeAA",
                "player_type":"#IMP_REQUEST__PLAYER_TYPE#",
                "grade":"0",
                "dsp_id":"tsr",
                "phase":"post",
                "ctry":"#IMP_REQUEST__CTRY#"
            },
            "device":{
                "os":"#DEVICE__OS#",
                "model":"#DEVICE__MODEL#",
                "device_type":"0",
                "locale":"#DEVICE__LOCALE#",
                "maker":"#DEVICE__MAKER#",
                "ua":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0",
                "device_id":"unknown",
                "ip":"117.197.100.116",
                "version":"#DEVICE__VERSION#"
            },
            "user":{
                "ad_user_id":""
            },
            "info":{
                "req_time":"#INFO__REQ_TIME#",
                "api_version":"1.2"
            }
        },
        "preroll":{
            "imp_request":{
                "dsp_data":{
                    "slotid":"05N72",
                    "test":"N",
                    "ver":"1.0",
                    "ownerid":"S6sTb99wgWw0",
                    "vid":"v0fdatJtMw8tJMB8tmrJeAA"
                },
                "cp_id":"81PaW",
                "replay":"#IMP_REQUEST__REPLAY#",
                "content_id":"v0fdatJtMw8tJMB8tmrJeAA",
                "player_type":"#IMP_REQUEST__PLAYER_TYPE#",
                "grade":"0",
                "dsp_id":"tsr",
                "phase":"pre",
                "ctry":"#IMP_REQUEST__CTRY#"
            },
            "device":{
                "os":"#DEVICE__OS#",
                "model":"#DEVICE__MODEL#",
                "device_type":"0",
                "locale":"#DEVICE__LOCALE#",
                "maker":"#DEVICE__MAKER#",
                "ua":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0",
                "device_id":"unknown",
                "ip":"117.197.100.116",
                "version":"#DEVICE__VERSION#"
            },
            "user":{
                "ad_user_id":""
            },
            "info":{
                "req_time":"#INFO__REQ_TIME#",
                "api_version":"1.2"
            }
        }
    },
    "should_protect_contents":"false",
    "thumbnail":{
        "edit":{
            "url":"http://t1.daumcdn.net/thumb/C640x360/?fname=http%3A%2F%2Ft1.daumcdn.net%2Ftvpot%2Fthumb%2Fv0fdatJtMw8tJMB8tmrJeAA%2Fthumb.png.edit"
        },
        "mini":{
            "url":"http://t1.daumcdn.net/thumb/C138x78/?fname=http%3A%2F%2Ft1.daumcdn.net%2Ftvpot%2Fthumb%2Fv0fdatJtMw8tJMB8tmrJeAA%2Fthumb.png.mini"
        },
        "main":{
            "url":"http://t1.daumcdn.net/thumb/C640x360/?fname=http%3A%2F%2Ft1.daumcdn.net%2Ftvpot%2Fthumb%2Fv0fdatJtMw8tJMB8tmrJeAA%2Fthumb.png"
        }
    },
    "tracking":{
        "count":"1",
        "tracking":[
            {
                "sec":"0",
                "type":"running_time",
                "url":"http://tvpot.daum.net/player/ClipStart.do?vid=v0fdatJtMw8tJMB8tmrJeAA&cprog=MAIN&mprog=HIGH"
            }
        ]
    },
    "tid":"e8f0aa7b021b970e85ddf863c2de5fa3",
    "vid":"v0fdatJtMw8tJMB8tmrJeAA"
}
```

Comment: thanks guy,That can solve my question,but can you tell me how to find the Daum Tv api?You know Korean?

Comment: @MapleStory - Http Debugger

Comment: @MapleStory - i have done lot of work with HTTP automation, hence have basic idea of how things work.